# Can an Oracle procedure's resultset output be used in a select statement?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

Basically, I'd like to write a procedure that contains a complex query whose output will be used in several places in the application. So I'd like to keep just one copy of the complex query inside a procedure if possible. If not, what would be an alternative solution. Is something like the following possible in Oracle PL/SQL? Thanks a lot.

```
   TYPE retCur  IS REF CURSOR;

   PROCEDURE get_rows (
      c_OutCursor             OUT retCur
      );
   BEGIN
      OPEN c_OutCursor FOR
        SELECT * FROM some_table;
   END get_rows;

   PROCEDURE use_rows
   BEGIN

      SELECT a.some_columns, b.some_columns
        FROM tableA a, get_rows b
       WHERE a.id = b.id;

   END;
```

Comment: To "keep" a complex query (so that you don't have to write the same code more than once), you should write a VIEW, not a PROCEDURE. If your concern is also that the query takes a long time to complete, and only want to compute the resultset once (and have it updated when the base data changes), you could use a MATERIALIZED VIEW, perhaps with REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT if it qualifies for that.

Comment: Which problem are you trying to solve? Typing the select only once? Paying the query execution cost only once? Both? There are different solutions depending on your requirement,